# VBA Command button that glows when user moves mouse on it?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create command button that glows during mouseover? It is not in userform, it will be placed directly in the sheet. It must be transparent and glows when user moves mouse on it (without clicking). I tried to create MouseMove event, but I get the error message *"Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method"*.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Me.CommandButton1.Glow = 17

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this a while ago and could not find anything, I got creative and used a very light colour that would change to a brighter version of the same colour when highlighted

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work" - is there an error message, does the glow effect fail to appear, does it occur when you move your mouse over a region other than the button, or something else? Also, have you put this code into a worksheet module (in which case it won't respond to an event) or a standalone module?

Comment: @jsheeran I got Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @EuanM28 that may work in my case, can you please share your code? I am still new in VBA and trying to learn as much as possible

Comment: It's likely that `CommandButton1` isn't a member of the object in which you're declaring your sub. Do you still get an error message if you try it with `Sheet1.CommandButton1` instead, substituting your worksheet name for Sheet1?

Comment: @Jsheeran My sheet is called Menu. Used code Menu.CommandButton1.Glow = 17 and got Run-time error 424, Object required

Comment: Try `Sheets("Menu").CommandButton1.Glow = 17`.

Comment: Pretty sure the CommandButton doesn't have a Glow property.

Comment: I'd probably use something like `Me.CommandButton1.BackColor = &HFF0000`, then add a label slightly larger than the command button with transparent background/border and _sent to back_ with another MouseMove event `Me.CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8000000F` to revert the button to the normal colour when you stop hovering over it.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, great idea, thanks! And yep, sadly CommandButton doesn't have a glow property.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook: That is how I also do it :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against command buttons in general. I think they are terribly visually unappealing.  Instead, i would use two labels: one stacked on top of the other. I believe mousemove works for ActiveX labels on the worksheet itself.

The first label should have a border and the second label is essentially the text of the button. The reason you want two labels stacked is to both vertically and horizontally align the button text.

You will want to use both mousemove events and assign them to trigger the same procedure.

You can achieve a variety of glow-like effects from the procedure. You can access some of the built-in shape outline effects or even preload a GIF image around the button while changing its visibility on/off as necessary during the mousemove events.

The link below is a good resource to see comparison between old-looking controls versus modern-looking controls. The concept is the same although you are not using a userform:

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/build-modern-vba-userforms